# Posting request to Amazon MWS services

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I have been wasting few days on this issue already...
The main problem is - I dont know how to POST data.
I would like to start by getting OrderReferenceDetails.
by looking at [MWS Scratchpad](https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html) (API Section: Off Amazon payments, Operation: GetOferenceDetails).

As I understand, first thing I should do, is to calculate signature. So by using this [Amazon developer guide](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mwsportal/doc/en_US/bde/MWSDeveloperGuide._V344220616_.pdf), and taking values in example in scratchpad, I created string, from which I calculated signature. This string looks like this

```
POST
mws.amazonservices.com
/offamazonpayments_sandbox/2013-01-01
Action=GetOrderReferenceDetails&AmazonOrderReferenceId=[_my order reference id_]&AWSAccessKeyId=[_my access key_]&SellerId=[_my seller id_]&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2014-11-04T12%3a15%3a38.1988397Z&Version=2013-01-01
```

So I hash this and get a signature, then I should add it to line of query parameters like `&Signature=[_my clalculated signature]`

Function I use to calculate signature:

```
private static String sign(String data, String secretKey)
{
    String result = null;
    KeyedHashAlgorithm algorithm = new HMACSHA256();
    Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    algorithm.Key = encoding.GetBytes(secretKey);
    result = Convert.ToBase64String(algorithm.ComputeHash(encoding.GetBytes(data.ToCharArray())));
    return result;
}
```

Problem start here (I think). Scratchpad provides "data" to post, but I cant understand, how to use it (copy-paste from scratchpad):

```
POST /OffAmazonPayments_Sandbox/2013-01-01?AWSAccessKeyId=
  &Action=GetOrderReferenceDetails
  &SellerId=
  &SignatureVersion=2
  &Timestamp=2014-11-04T12%3A37%3A58Z
  &Version=2013-01-01
  &Signature=rEqRKP27Pklu%2BAmRLR%2ByRpUtfhNsVOWuGTQ7s%2FgkB2w%3D
  &SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256
  &AmazonOrderReferenceId= HTTP/1.1
Host: mws.amazonservices.com
x-amazon-user-agent: AmazonJavascriptScratchpad/1.0 (Language=Javascript)
Content-Type: text/xml
```

What is this? I am familiar of making request like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "text/xml";
request.Host = "whatever host I need to use";
request.ContentLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(dataAsString);
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataAsString);
using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
     dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
}
try
{
    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string responseAsString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
catch (WebException exception)
{
    HttpWebResponse exceptionalResponse = exception.Response as HttpWebResponse;
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(exceptionalResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        String responseAsString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Questions are:

Am I calculating signature properly?

How to construct web request?

Thanks for reading and trying to help!

EDIT:

Well, I finally got a response from MWS Amazon, that is not an error!
Steps I did to make it work:

Construct string that will be signed by hand - order of query parameters is important.

Construct url where I will post data by hand - again, order is important, but different from string signed before. Keys in signed string should be sorted using lexicographic byte ordering. Well, I dont know what kind of animal is that, so thats why I did everything by hand, by example taking scratchpad.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea of c#, but found this https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/orders/orders/v20130901/cSharp.html helpful for other languages. You can take a look in how everything is generated in the code

Comment: lexicographic byte ordering is the kind of animal that has 0 < A < B < Z < a < b < z, in short: ordering by ASCII value

Comment: Hey man, I am having the same problem. Is it possible for you to post the signature code in the question?

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for a few days and it came down to the order of the parameters. I tried to find a solution to order the parameters without doing it by hand and finally found the answer. I created a SortedDictionary() at first still did not work. Then I saw an example from Claytondus nuget package that works with MWS and he had SortedDictionary(StringComparer.Ordinal). Once I did that it sorted correctly and got a good response.